# matplotlib keyboard focus in wrong window

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

This simple test code works fine under anaconda python, but when run through PyCharm, or from the command line, the keyboard focus remains in the wrong window, either in the PyCharm editor or the command line respectively. In other words when I type "q" to quit, I just see a "q" appear in the editor window, or on the command line (respectively). When I run it under anaconda python it works correctly, printing the detected key event and quitting if it is "q".

Why doesn't this work as expected?

```
# TestKeyboard.py

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([.1, .1, .8, .8])

# Keypress 'q' to quit
def keypress(event):
    print 'event key = %s'%event.key
    if event.key == 'q':
        plt.close()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', keypress)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What does "under anaconda" mean?

Comment: What does "run through PyCharm" means? Did you set the python environment in PyCharm?
If the answer is, "please select "preferences" -> "Project" -> "Project interpreter", and select the python environment you want PyCharm to run your code." the question is probably a duplicate. Hope this helps anyway!

Comment: I installed anaconda python (with Spyder IDE) and developed  some code using matplotlib that worked fine. Then I discovered PyCharm, that seems so much better, except the code I developed under anaconda does not work under PyCharm. Yes I saw the Project Interpreter selector and tried different alternatives, I found one that works except for the keyboard mapping.